# SWT Layouts - Cannot vertically center Text widget within GridLayout

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm in the process of converting many SWT labels in our application into text widgets because we need to make our software more accessible. Screen readers have a hard time reading label values but can with ease if we use read-only text widgets.

After converting several labels within a gridlayout into read-only text, we can't seem to get the text to be vertically centered. Below is a simple calculator example where we're seeing the same behavior. I've played around with SWT.CENTER, SWT.FILL both on GridData as well as Text but can't seem to get the control vertically centered.

```
public void initUI() {

        GridLayout g1 = new GridLayout(4, true);
        g1.horizontalSpacing = 4;
        g1.verticalSpacing = 4;
        g1.marginBottom = 5;
        g1.marginTop = 5;
        shell.setLayout(g1);

        String[] buttons = {
                "Cls", "Bck", "", "Close", "7", "8", "9", "/", "4",
                "5", "6", "*", "1", "2", "3", "-", "0", ".", "=", "+"
        };

        Text display = new Text(shell, SWT.SINGLE);
        GridData gridData = new GridData();
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 4;
        gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        display.setLayoutData(gridData);

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

            if (i == 2) {
                Label lbl = new Label(shell, SWT.CENTER);
                GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false);
                lbl.setLayoutData(gd);
            } else {
               Text btn = new Text(shell,SWT.SINGLE | SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.BORDER);
               btn.setText(buttons[i]);
               GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true);

               gd.widthHint = 50;
               gd.heightHint = 30;
               btn.setLayoutData(gd);
               btn.selectAll();


            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean you want the text *horizontally* centered (it's already vertically centered). Make this change and it will be centered both ways (I added the `SWT.CENTER` to the `Text`):

```
Text btn = new Text(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.READ_ONLY
    | SWT.BORDER | SWT.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way that works for me.

```
Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.CENTER);
label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
label.setText("\nText");
```

The hack is to suffix new lines (\n) to the text.